# Product of normal subgroups of galois group

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

This is A-5.14 in Advanced Modern Algebra by Rotman.

If f is separable in $k[x]$ and $E/k$ is a splitting field. If $f=gh$ in $k[x]$, and $B/k$ and $C/k$ are intermediate fields of g and h, respectively.

For part iii, given $B \cap C = k$, need to prove $Gal(E/B)Gal(E/C)=Gal(E/k)$.

I already showed the two subgroups are normal, and $Gal(E/k)=Gal(E/B \cap C)=Gal(E/B) \vee Gal(E/C)$. I Also know $Gal(E/k)/Gal(E/B) \cong Gal(B/k)$.

The hint is $Gal(E/k) \cong Gal(B/k) \times Gal(C/k)$, but I don't know how it works.

Comment: What edition are you looking at? In my version, (1) this is Exercise 4.17, (2) the fact that $\mathrm{Gal}(E/k) \cong \mathrm{Gal}(B/k) \times \mathrm{Gal}(C/k)$ is not a hint but rather part (iv) of the question.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Third edition

Answer (score 0):

$\def\Gal{\operatorname{Gal}}$
You have observed correctly that
$$\Gal(E/k) = \Gal(E/B) \vee \Gal(E/C),$$
which follows from the fundamental theorem of Galois theory and considering the fixed field of the right-hand side.
Here $H \vee K = \langle H, K \rangle$ is the group generated by $H$ and $K$.
Now note that if either $H$ or $K$ is normal then $H \vee K = HK$, and this completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. For the case that neither $H$ nor $K$ is normal. Is it true that $HK$ is not a subgroup, so $H \vee K$ is the subgroup generated by $HK$?

Comment: @Halulu If neither $H$ nor $K$ is normal, the product set $HK$ may or may not be a subgroup. $HK$ a subgroup iff $HK = KH$. This is all covered in Proposition A-4.69 and Exercise A-4.82.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I want to confirm that in this case, $H \vee K$ is the subgroup generated by the subset $HK$.

Comment: @Halulu I understand your question now. Yes, that's true, because $H \cup K \subseteq HK \subseteq \langle H \cup K \rangle$, so $H \vee K = \langle H \cup K \rangle \le \langle HK \rangle \le H \vee K$.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation.